# Problem on installing Pycaret Full on Google Colab

Tags: python, pip, google-colaboratory, pycaret

I'm trying to install Pycaret Full on my Google Colab:

```py
pip install pycaret[full]
```

But it's taking too long (over 6h) and it doesn't finish...

Answer (score 2):

This seems related to the new dependency resolver of `pip`. Running above command in Google Colab will yield the following message several times:

> INFO: This is taking longer than usual. You might need to provide the dependency resolver with stricter constraints to reduce runtime. If you want to abort this run, you can press Ctrl + C to do so. To improve how pip performs, tell us what happened here: https://pip.pypa.io/surveys/backtracking

You can see that `pip` tries to download several versions of the same package. An issue with suggestions how to cope with this problem has been opened [here](https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/9215).

One of the suggestions that helps for now is to choose the old resolver behavior with `--use-deprecated=legacy-resolver`:

```py
pip install --use-deprecated=legacy-resolver pycaret[full]
```

A test run installed `pycaret` in Google Colab in about 2 minutes.

Comment: This pip seems to have resolved the issue for now. The pip took 2min20s.

Comment: Thanks! Trying to install pycaret on ubuntu has been driving me crazy before I found this!